What's the point of putting a resistor here?
If we only want the voltage potential \$v_0\$, what can go wrong by removing \$R_L\$?

source of image: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rq7dmkcSco0&pp=ygUnbXVsdGlzdGFnZSBhbXBsaWZpZXIgYW5hbG9nIGVsZWN0cm9uaWNz

RL can have any appropriate value for the circuit application. It represents whatever the circuit is designed to drive. So you may need to include it to get reasonably accurate results unless whatever is being driven has very high impedance.
If you choose a very high or very low value the results will be quite different from the results if the actual load RL is of the same order of magnitude as RC.
The output coupling capacitor (in fact, all the capacitors) appear(s) to be infinitely large, which might be a bit hard to realize in practice and may pose difficulties in simulation. That does, however, vastly simplify the paper-and-pen analysis of the circuit.

RL is not part of the amplifier.
RL, together with Vsig and Rsig are the testbench with which you are testing the amplifier.1
This type of amplifier has an output resistance of roughly RC. As you vary the load, its gain will vary. To get a realistic measurement of the gain, distortion, maximum output signal etc, you need to test it with a realistic load.
Note that if this amplifier was intended to drive a different type of load, capacitive, inductive, or non-linear for instance, then you would need to simulate that load to get useful answers from your testing.
1The DC block capacitor, as its value is given as \$\infty\$, is also part of the testbench. Amplifiers like that will usually have an actual finite-valued DC block capacitor in the amplifier output, in which case you would model its true value, as it affects low frequency gain into a load, and you may be concerned about its switch-on transient.

RL is not a resistor in that sense, but the payload or the purpose of the circuit. A load is required, e.g. with a loudspeaker, as otherwise the upstream capacitance cannot be recharged.

It means you want voltage V0 to the load Rl.
Whatever your circuit does, it needs to be able to drive the load you want. Of course for analytical purposes the load may be irrelevant such as with ideal op-amp circuits so it may be omitted. But if you are building say an audio amplifier, it makes a lot of difference if the load is an 8 ohm speaker, a 32 ohm headphone, or 10 kohm line input.
If you omit a load, a simulator may fail to simulate properly, or it may fail to start a simulation due to missing DC conditions at the output node.

Basic idea

What's the point of putting a resistor here?

The resistor is necessary to ensure that the coupling capacitor at the output charges up to the Q2's quiescent collector voltage.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab


If we only want the voltage potential v0, what can go wrong by removing RL?

If RL is missing, the capacitor will not be charged and the voltage across it will be 0 V. The output voltage after the capacitor will be "lifted" to the collector voltage and will not vary around ground potential.

simulate this circuit

If this brief answer does not satisfy you, you can review the detailed story below.
Building and exploring the circuit
Let's build and analyze it step by step to follow the circuit evolution.
To grasp the main concept of output biasing, we need to strip the circuit of unnecessary details, leaving only the essentials. To this end, we can represent the common-emitter amplifier stage (Q2) as two voltage sources in series - one producing the AC input voltage Vin, and the other producing the DC quiescent voltage Vqsc.
For the purposes of our intuitive understanding we can replace the AC input voltage source with a DC source and consider the three typical voltage values - 0, 1, and -1V. This allows us to examine circuit operation through the simpler DC live simulation and by including DC meters.
Emulated-capacitor circuit
If we assume that the supply voltage is Vcc = 10 V, then we need to "lift" the input voltage by 5 V to achieve a maximum swing of 10V.
No output biasing
Vin = 0 V

simulate this circuit
Vin = 1 V DC

simulate this circuit
Vin = -1 V DC

simulate this circuit
So, when Vin varies from -1 V to 1 V, Vout varies from 4 V to 6 V.

Vin = 1 V AC: The same applies when Vin is a sinusoidal voltage with an amplitude of 1 V.

simulate this circuit

Output biasing added
Now we need to lower the voltage back by 5V to make it "wiggle" around ground. For this purpose, we connect a 5 V bias voltage source Vbias in series so that its voltage is subtracted.
Vin = 0 V

simulate this circuit
Vin = 1 V DC

simulate this circuit
Vin = -1 V DC

simulate this circuit
Since the graphs of Vin and Vout coincide, I have introduced a small offset of 80 mV so that we can see both of them.

Vin = 1 V AC:

simulate this circuit
As above, I have introduced a 80 mV offset to see both Vin and Vout graphs.

Real-capacitor circuit
As we can see from the OP's schematic, the bias voltage source Vbias is implemented with a capacitor C which should charge up to 5 V through the load resistor.
No load connected
If this resistor is missing, the circuit is interrupted and the capacitor cannot charge. Its voltage remains 0 V and the output voltage follows the voltage before the capacitor.

simulate this circuit

Load connected
When the load RL is connected, the circuit is closed...

simulate this circuit
... and the capacitor charges to 5 V (for clarity, Vin = 0 V).

So, when Vin begins oscillating around ground...

simulate this circuit
... Vout also oscillates around ground.

More resources
This was a story about the output biasing. For completeness, see also my story about the input biasing.

The circuit will operate without RL connected, but output voltage measurements will be incorrect.  RC and RL form a voltage divider in the positive half-cycles of the signal.  This limits the maximum positive peak voltage value.  Without RL, RC can pull the output all the way up to Vcc.  With RL, you can see the harmonic distortion caused by an asymmetrical output impedance.
